# which is the latest C cross compiler for u-boot2019 and linux kernel?

Tags: linux, gcc, u-boot

i want to compile u-boot2019,but it is for gcc6.0+.

```
*** Your GCC is older than 6.0 and is not supported
```

I can only search for"arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" and "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" for 2014.

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 1):

You can get a version 7.4.1 toolchain from [Linaro](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/) and a version 8.3.0 one from [Arm](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

*Update*: you can now get  a version 7.5.0 toolchain from [Linaro](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/), and a version 9.2.1 from [Arm](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tools/buildman/buildman` to fetch a toolchain for you (and also use it) from kernel.org, or you can also get one from https://toolchains.bootlin.com/